# Click event in not binding to inner elements in directive

Tags: angularjs

I am using a directive on a container which contains different action buttons. I want to bind click event on each button. But its not working.

Please find link function:

```
return function(scope, iElement, iAttributes, containerCtrl) {
  iElement.bind('click', function(){
                    console.log('decline_wrap click');//working
                });

  iElement.find('.a').bind('click', function(){
                    console.log('a click');//not working
                });

  iElement.find('.b').bind('click', function(){
                    console.log('b click');//not working
                });
}
```

Comment: you can put scope functions on element clicks on the template itself...no need to bind

Answer (score 0):

What V31 said:

```
return function(scope, iElement, iAttributes, containerCtrl) {
  scope.declineWrap =  function(){
                             console.log('decline_wrap click');
                       };

  scope.aFunction = function(){
                          console.log('a click');
                     };

  scope.bFunction =  function(){
                          console.log('b click');
                      };
}
```

And then in the html you put the ng-click directive with the function of your choosing, something like this:

```
<div class="a" ng-click="aFunction()"></div>
<div class="b" ng-click="bFunction()"></div>
```

Comment: Is this possible without using ng-click in html?

Comment: why don't you want ng-click in the html?